# calling setattr before 'self' is returned

Tags: python, setattr, luigi

I suspect this is kind of a klugefest on my part, but I'm working with the Luigi and Sciluigi modules which set a number of critical parameters PRIOR to 'self' being returned by an init. ANd if I try to manhandle these parameters AFTER self is returned, the Luigi.Parameter object masks them in such a way that I cant do what I need to do.

The luigi and sciluigi classes (as one uses them) contain no `__init__`. And if I try to insert an `__init__` or call `super(ChildClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` ...I get weird errors 'unexpected parameter' errors.

So a Sciluigi class looks like this...

```
class MyTask(sciluigi.task):
    param1 = sciluigi.Parameter(default='Yes') #String only
    param2 = sciluigi.Parameter(default='No')  #String only

    def out_target(self):
        return sciluigi.TargetInfo(self, self.out)

    def run(self):
        with self.out_target().open('w') as foofile:
            foofile.write('foo\n')
```

SO...I'm hoping I can dynamically set some parameters via setattr PRIOR to 'self' actually being returned. But setattr requires the object.

I was hoping I could do something like...

```
setattr(inspect.stack()[?][?], 'DynamicVar', sciluigi.Parameter(default='Yes') )
```

## EDIT: @Charles Duffy

Well, I'm not sure what info would be most helpful.

First issue is; I can't add an init. The actual code is below, with an `__init__`method added. I've included the resulting error if I try to run it. Its the same error is if I tr to run the super call to `__init__`

```
class FileConverter(sciluigi.Task):
    """
    """
    in_target   = None # Mandatory
    out = sciluigi.Parameter() # <file>
    exepath = sciluigi.Parameter(default = "") 

    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 'anything'

    def out_target(self):
        log.debug("In 'FileConverter.out_target'... ")
        return sciluigi.TargetInfo(self, self.out)

    def run(self):
        result = None
        command = ''.join([
                           self.exepath, _slash, "FileConverter ",
                           " -in ", self.in_target().path,
                           " -out ", self.out_target().path, 
                           " -out_type ", self.file_type
                           ])
        log.info("RUNNING COMMAND: " + command)
        result = self.ex(command)
        log.info("result: " + result[1])
```

### Error

```
2017-02-24 17:01:48 |  WARNING | Will not run MyWorkflow(instance_name=sciluigi_workflow) or any dependencies due to error in deps() method:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 697, in _add
    deps = task.deps()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/luigi/task.py", line 572, in deps
    return flatten(self._requires())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/luigi/task.py", line 544, in _requires
    return flatten(self.requires())  # base impl
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sciluigi/workflow.py", line 105, in requires
    workflow_output = self.workflow()
  File "/Users/mikes/Documents/Eclipseworkspace/Bioproximity/OpenMS-Python-Luigi/site-packages/Bioproximity/sciluigi_tasks/PipelineTest1.py", line 33, in workflow
    exepath = "/Applications/OpenMS-2.1.0/TOPP"
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sciluigi/workflow.py", line 145, in new_task
    newtask = sciluigi.new_task(instance_name, cls, self, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sciluigi/task.py", line 37, in new_task
    newtask = cls.from_str_params(kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/luigi/task.py", line 412, in from_str_params
    return cls(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/luigi/task_register.py", line 99, in __call__
    h[k] = instantiate()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/luigi/task_register.py", line 80, in instantiate
    return super(Register, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance_name'
```

### The second issue is:

If I wait for self to return, I can no longer differentiate between (for example using the above code)...

```
in_target   = None # Mandatory
out = sciluigi.Parameter() # <file>
```

If I do a `type(out)`, type reports that the parameter is just a string (not a sciluigi.Parameter object) so if I try to use a `ìsinstance(out, sciluigi.Parameter)...it returns False.

### The bottom line is:

I need to be able to set the sciluigi.Parameter objects dynamically (programatically) and subsequently be able to differentiate between a sciluigi.Parameter() object variable (like `out`) and a 'real' str() object (like `in_target`)

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: ...klugefest, indeed. Could you provide enough information for folks to reproduce the problem you had when trying to parameterize your constructor? (If `sciluigi` isn't built to accept unknown parameters that kind of thing *is* certainly possible, but there _are_ workarounds -- some of them might mean, for example, calling parent constructors manually rather than using `super()`).

Comment: ...which is to say: Better to fix the problems that come up when doing things the Right Way than to invent a messy hack.

Comment: It's not that you can't add an `__init__`. It's that you can't add an `__init__` **that doesn't take parameters**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for future reference, the answer to the isolated question, "How to...

```
setattr(<thisClassObject>, 'DynamicVar', sciluigi.Parameter(default='Yes') )
```

Is to use the `locals()` built in function. I.e.

```
locals()['DynamicVar'] = sciluigi.Parameter(default='Yes') #String only
```

This is a snippet of how I solved my particular kluge ;)

### deleteme.py

```
import sciluigi

class MyFooWriter(sciluigi.Task):
    locals()['outfile'] = sciluigi.Parameter(default='./foo.txt') #String only
    locals()['normalvar'] = 'Normalstring'
    print "pre-self-returned outfile type =", type(outfile)
    print "pre-self-returned normalvar type =", type(normalvar)
#     locals()['param1'] = 
    def out_foo(self):
        # raw_input("Enter...")
        return sciluigi.TargetInfo(self, self.outfile)

    def run(self):
        print "self.outfile type =", type(self.outfile)
        print "self.normalvar type =", type(self.normalvar)
        # raw_input("Enter...")        
        with self.out_foo().open('w') as foofile:
            foofile.write('foo\n')            


class MyWorkflow(sciluigi.WorkflowTask):
    def workflow(self):
        print 'Starting workflow...'
        foowriter = self.new_task('foowriter', MyFooWriter, outfile = 'testfile.txt')
        return foowriter        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sciluigi.run_local(main_task_cls=MyWorkflow)
```

### OUTPUT

```
pre-self-returned outfile type = <class 'sciluigi.parameter.Parameter'>
pre-self-returned normalvar type = <type 'str'>
Starting workflow...
2017-02-27 12:08:37 |     INFO | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-02-27 12:08:37 |     INFO | SciLuigi: MyWorkflow Workflow Started (logging to log/workflow_myworkflow_started_20170227_110837_278707.log)
2017-02-27 12:08:37 |     INFO | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-02-27 12:08:37 |     INFO | Task foowriter started
self.outfile type = <type 'str'>
self.normalvar type = <type 'str'>
2017-02-27 12:08:37 |     INFO | Task foowriter finished after 0.001s
Starting workflow...
2017-02-27 12:08:37 |     INFO | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-02-27 12:08:37 |     INFO | SciLuigi: MyWorkflow Workflow Finished (workflow log at log/workflow_myworkflow_started_20170227_110837_278707.log)
2017-02-27 12:08:37 |     INFO | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Accept and silently discard arguments in your constructor, like so:

```
class FileConverter(sciluigi.Task):
    def __init__(self, *_args, **_kwargs):
        self.var = 'anything'
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but unfortunately it doesn't work. The error message is coming from the ``__init__``` much deeper in the parent structure. In this case the class 'register'. You are right that fixing the deeper classes of the module is the best fix, but for now - I think the settattr kluge is the only workaround I see. ...ERROR..."return super(Register, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance_name'
 "